# GCC is not recognizing symbol table in my hand-made ELF file

Tags: elf, symbols, gcc

For learning purposes I've created (using a hex editor and some macros) the following ELF file:

```
hello.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

xxd hello.o:

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0100 3e00 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
00000030: 0000 0000 4000 3800 0000 4000 0400 0300  ....@.8...@.....
00000040: 0c00 0000 0300 0000 2000 0000 0000 0000  ........ .......
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4001 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
00000060: 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0600 0000 0100 0000 2200 0000 0000 0000  ........".......
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4601 0000 0000 0000  ........F.......
000000a0: 0e00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 1400 0000 0200 0000 2000 0000 0000 0000  ........ .......
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 5401 0000 0000 0000  ........T.......
000000e0: 1800 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1800 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 1c00 0000 0300 0000 2000 0000 0000 0000  ........ .......
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 6c01 0000 0000 0000  ........l.......
00000120: 2600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  &...............
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 6865 6c6c 6f00 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72  hello.Hello, wor
00000150: 6c64 2100 0000 0000 1100 0100 0000 0000  ld!.............
00000160: 0000 0000 0e00 0000 0000 0000 6865 6c6c  ............hell
00000170: 6f00 2e64 6174 6100 2e73 7472 7461 6200  o..data..strtab.
00000180: 2e73 796d 7461 6200 2e73 6873 7472 7461  .symtab..shstrta
00000190: 6200                                     b.
```

I wish to link it together with a C program (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char hello[];

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", hello);
    return 0;
}
```

However, running `gcc main.o hello.o` shows an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

readelf -s hello.o:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 1 entry:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000    14 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 hello
```

(readelf output is similar to object files created by GCC)

**Why doesn't GCC accept my created object file?**

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the same commands as you with the file you provided but it failed in the same way as yours. However with a newer hellow.c as such

```
char hello[] = "Hello World";
```

with the following commands it worked

```
$ gcc -c hellow.c
$ gcc main.c hellow.o -o main
$ ./main
Hello World
```

There are some key differences between `hellow.o` and your `hello.o`

```
$ nm hellow.o
0000000000000000 D hello
$ nm hello.o 
nm: hello.o: no symbols
$ readelf -s hellow.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS hellow.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     7: 0000000000000000    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 hello
```

If we strip `hellow.o` it won't work as expected. The file looks like this

```
$ xxd hellow.o
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0100 3e00 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 9801 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 4000 0900 0800  ....@.....@.....
00000040: 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6400 0047 4343  Hello World..GCC
00000050: 3a20 2844 6562 6961 6e20 362e 332e 302d  : (Debian 6.3.0-
00000060: 3138 2b64 6562 3975 3129 2036 2e33 2e30  18+deb9u1) 6.3.0
00000070: 2032 3031 3730 3531 3600 0000 0000 0000   20170516.......
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0400 f1ff  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0300 0200  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0300 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0300 0500  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0300 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0a00 0000 1100 0200  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0c00 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0068 656c 6c6f 772e 6300 6865 6c6c 6f00  .hellow.c.hello.
00000150: 002e 7379 6d74 6162 002e 7374 7274 6162  ..symtab..strtab
00000160: 002e 7368 7374 7274 6162 002e 7465 7874  ..shstrtab..text
00000170: 002e 6461 7461 002e 6273 7300 2e63 6f6d  ..data..bss..com
00000180: 6d65 6e74 002e 6e6f 7465 2e47 4e55 2d73  ment..note.GNU-s
00000190: 7461 636b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  tack............
000001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1b00 0000 0100 0000  ................
000001e0: 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000001f0: 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  @...............
00000200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2100 0000 0100 0000  ........!.......
00000220: 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000230: 4000 0000 0000 0000 0c00 0000 0000 0000  @...............
00000240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2700 0000 0800 0000  ........'.......
00000260: 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000270: 4c00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  L...............
00000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2c00 0000 0100 0000  ........,.......
000002a0: 3000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  0...............
000002b0: 4c00 0000 0000 0000 2e00 0000 0000 0000  L...............
000002c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002d0: 0100 0000 0000 0000 3500 0000 0100 0000  ........5.......
000002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000002f0: 7a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  z...............
00000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000330: 8000 0000 0000 0000 c000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000340: 0700 0000 0700 0000 0800 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000350: 1800 0000 0000 0000 0900 0000 0300 0000  ................
00000360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000370: 4001 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000  @...............
00000380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 0000 0300 0000  ................
000003a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003b0: 5001 0000 0000 0000 4500 0000 0000 0000  P.......E.......
000003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

Comment: If nothing else comes up, I'm going to award the bounty to your answer, because by taking a closer look at the symbols, I realized that I was missing an empty, zero-filled symbol which ELF files require. After the change, GCC and Clang still refuse to link the files, but it works with TCC. The original question still stands - what magic does GCC and Clang expect in object files that I'm missing?

Comment: I am reading source code for `nm`. Will update when I find what's the reason for this.

Comment: `elf_slurp_symbol_table` from elfcode.h in binutils returns 0 for your file for nm to read symbols for `nm`. Then the error is printed out from `display_rel_file`  in line nm.c:1126 for binutils 2.34 for me.